# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 500, placement implies 1, Python and Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I'm importing just two columns from .xlsx file and I would like to calculate some stuff (mean, deviation, percent change) and then I would like to plot all this. First part doesn't give me any problems, but plotting does.

My code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math

df = pd.read_excel('KDPrviIzbor.xlsx', sheetname='List1', index_col = 0)
ch = df.pct_change(periods=252)

ma = np.mean(ch)*100
std = np.std(ch)*100

x = np.linspace(-100,100,500)
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x,ma,std))

plt.show()
```

But when I run my code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/David/PythonStuff/normal_distribution.py", line 21, in <module> plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x,ma,std))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 1579, in normpdf return 1./(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)*np.exp(-0.5 * (1./sigma*(x - mu))**2)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 534, in wrapper dtype=dtype)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 220, in __init__ data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3383, in __init__ ndim=1, fastpath=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2101, in make_block placement=placement)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 77, in __init__ len(self.values), len(self.mgr_locs)))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 500, placement implies 1`
```

I figured that the problem is in:

`plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x,ma,std))`

but I cannot solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: could you show how `df` looks like? e.g. the output of `df.head()`. and can you try to calculate `y = mlab.normpdf(x,ma,std)` without plotting?I guess you will also get an error then. And can you show the output of `print ma` and `print std`? my bet is that they are not floatsbut a pandas series.

Comment: @FabianRost, output of df.head() is:               VEP
Date              
2005-05-16  4.1729
2005-05-17  4.1700
2005-05-18  4.3400
2005-05-19  4.3600
2005-05-20  4.3700

Comment: Output of print(ma): VEP    7.14688
dtype: float64 and output of print(std): VEP    19.335596
dtype: float64

Comment: Hello again! I figured it out. Correct code of line is: plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x,int(ma),int(std)))
The only problem is that I don't know why does that work. Anyway, thanks @FabianRost for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ma` and `std` are `pandas.Series` objects in your example. The reason is, that `np.mean` applied to a `pandas.DataFrame` returns a `pandas.Series`.
However, mlab.normpdf(x,ma,std) expects float values or numpy arrays as inputs.
You could simply convert `ma` and `std` to floats by `ma = float(ma)`.
I would not suggest to use `int(ma)` as you pointed out in your comment, because that would cut away the decimals.

Comment: Fabian, thanks again. I used float(ma) and float(std) and now works as it should.