# Concatenating values from columns to a list in Python

Tags: python

I am working on a project which does automated descriptive analysis on data. In a line of code I am sending a row of a dataframe and I want all the values in columns returned in a single list.

The line of code is :

```
file_name1['validate'] = file_name1.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x[2]) + [x[3]] + [x[4]] + [x[5]] + [x[0]] + [x[1]], axis=1)
```

and the filename1 looks like this

```
Value_share_total_next Value_share_total_prev Path                                            IYA      upper      lower  
1497852                1270937                ['CVS + ALB + LNG CORP WO HI CENSUS TA']   117.85415  91.945763  66.936457
```

I want to concatenate these values inside a list, and I am getting the error as :

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1
```

EDIT : The problem I am facing is only if the length of my dataframe is exactly 1. If the length of my dataframe is > 1 then the line of code is working. I could add an if else condition but I need to know why it is not working. Can I not apply a function to a single or of the dataframe?

Comment: this may help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677780/valueerror-wrong-number-of-items-passed-500-placement-implies-1-python-and-pa

Comment: @technerd I have checked that question already but it doesn't relate to my situation. The line of code should be working actually.

Answer (score 0):

For every row you pass a list of 6 items when there is only one space allocated (one column: 'validate'). To make sure pandas understand the data type you want to pass (a list) and doesn't try to unpack it you can use parentheses:

```py
file_name1['validate'] = file_name1.apply(lambda x: (ast.literal_eval(x[2]) + [x[3]] + [x[4]] + [x[5]] + [x[0]] + [x[1]]), axis=1)
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: It did not work. I have made an edit to my question. If you could help me it would be great. Thanks in advance.