# apply + list comprehension gives ValueError when returned list length is same as number of data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas

This question is born of [this comment thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826334/2799941).  Using Pandas `0.20.3`.

I'm trying to understand why an `apply()` operation throws the error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

This specific flavor of Pandas `ValueError` is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677780/valueerror-wrong-number-of-items-passed-500-placement-implies-1-python-and-pa) [uncommon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196907/valueerror-wrong-number-of-items-passed-meaning-and-suggestions), but it usually comes from a more obvious attempt to cram a bunch of elements into a data structure that is designed for a lesser capacity.  The same thing must be going on here, but I can't figure out why.

Given a data frame with columns of integers `A` and `B`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2], 'B': [3,4]})
df
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

I can construct a new column, `C`, which is a column of lists.
Each list in `C` contains values from `A` and `B`.
`C` should look like:

```
     C
[1, 3]
[2, 4]
```

I am choosing to build `C` using `apply()` and a list comprehension:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: [val for val in x], axis=1)
```

(For now, please overlook the possibility that this is not the most elegant way to achieve this goal - it's mainly a route to get to the error I'm confused about.)

This throws the `ValueError` noted above.
**But**, I can create lists with *more* items per row without difficulty:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: [val for val in x]+[1], axis=1)
df
   A  B          C
0  1  3  [1, 3, 1]
1  2  4  [2, 4, 1]
```

I would have thought that I'd get the same error, just with `Wrong number of items passed 3...` instead of `2`.

I can also create `C` with fewer items:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: [val for val in x][:1], axis=1)
df
   A  B    C
0  1  3  [1]
1  2  4  [2]
```

Additionally, `C` builds when the first row's list length is shorter or longer than `[1,3]`, but fails when the first row's list length matches `len([1,3])`, even if subsequent list lengths are different:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: [val for val in x if val != 1], axis=1) # this works
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: [val for val in x if val != 4], axis=1) # this fails
```

Given all of these different cases, I don't understand what `placement implies 1` is referring to, and why I can't just make the lists in `C` with the elements of `A` and `B`, using this approach.
How am I misinterpreting this error message?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on `0.21`. But I can tell you that pandas special cases lists and numpy arrays that have the same width as the dataframe.

Comment: It's also the same reason you can do `df.apply(tuple, 1)` but not `df.apply(list, 1)`

Comment: Interesting - can you point me to anywhere that the "special cases" thing is discussed?

Comment: I think the most pertinent link would be this: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16321

Comment: Also, a really solid workaround (and extremely fast) would be: `df = pd.Series(df.values.tolist()).to_frame('C')`

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, I asked a similar question here, and the GitHub issue link is also mentioned by the answerer here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928415/why-does-df-applytuple-work-but-not-df-applylist

Comment: Does the *missing* leading apostrophe on df[C'] = df.apply(lambda x: [val for val in x], axis=1) make a difference?  Your ide thinks so.

Comment: Thanks cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I'll have a look.  Funny - you actually had chimed in on one of the answers on the question that started all of this, on Aug 22, then you asked this question you just mentioned here on Aug 28.  I wonder if it got you thinking?  Wim's answer to you suggested this was related to buggy behavior, and if it's fixed in `0.21` I guess this isn't a relevant question anymore.  I'll keep it open for a bit longer while I go through the docs, but thinking you've probably resolved my question here.

Comment: @Rookie, good catch, that was just copy error.  Fixed now.

Comment: Indeed it did :-) Pandas does some funky stuff every now and then that's worth a question. Case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137355/why-is-pandas-dataframe-apply-printing-out-junk

Comment: Good to know your question was resolved. You could write an answer if you want.

Comment: I suspect what was happening is that pandas was returning a full dataframe (2 columns) from the apply and trying to force it into one column.  I think that's what 2 items, 1 place means

Comment: After I try, `df.apply(lambda x: [val for val in x if val != 2], axis=1)` , I getting shocked ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this behavior results from a mix of **(a)** `.apply()` trying to be helpful and **(b)** abusing `.apply()` as a means of outputting non-scalar values.  It has been fixed in Pandas version `0.21`.

I've cobbled together this explanation from various Pandas Github issues pages [[1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16321), [2](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15628), [3](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14370)], some of which are also linked to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928415/why-does-df-applytuple-work-but-not-df-applylist).  It's not really an explanation of *why* this happens at the implementation level, but it at least substantively answers the question.
Happy to accept any relevannt updates/edits.

**On `.apply()` trying to be helpful:**
If a multi-dimensional value is returned that has the same shape as the input DataFrame, `apply` will infer a DataFrame as output:

> TomAugspurger: DataFrame.apply tries to infer an output based on the result. The result of your output is inferred to be a DataFrame with the same columns. [[ref]](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16321#issuecomment-300572545)
>
> jreback: The issue is .apply has to try to figure out what you are returning and how that maps to the starting data. [[ref]](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15628#issuecomment-285212926)

**On abusing `.apply()` as a means of outputting non-scalar values:**
In short, don't if you can avoid it.  If you must, expect occasionally funny results.

> jreback: Note that returning non-scalars is generally not recommended and is not efficiently supported. [[ref]](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15628#issuecomment-285212926)